# Why can't I see NSString values when tapping on object in the Xcode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-debugger

Anyone know how I can see the NSString value like I see the NSInteger value without tapping on the I or "eye" icon?

p.s I don't use any optimisation in debug build setting.

[image: xcode debugger show one object data]

Comment: This happens to me too. I think these are Xcode/gdb bugs or limitations. I suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: Previous versions of Xcode, long before ARC, did show the string values and crashed on undefined values. Try context menu -> View Value As… -> Custom Type -> `NSString*`.